# Run command from .bashrc in detached docker container

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I'm running a docker container in detached mode, and I'm having difficulty running a command that's in the container's `~/.bashrc`.

Inside the docker container's `~/.bashrc`:

`labserve () {
  jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --allow-root --no-browser --NotebookApp.token=''
}`

If I start the container with

`$ docker run -d image -p 8888:8888 --name jupyterbox`

I'd like to be able to tell the image to tell the detached container to open up jupyterlab with the following command:

`$ docker exec jupyterbox bash -c labserve`

however, when I do that, I get the error

`bash: labinit: command not found`

On the other hand, if I do

`$ docker run -it jupyterbox bash
root@4e344655fc31:/home# labserve`

The command runs correctly, and opens up a jupyterlab within my docker container running on port 8888.

How do I `exec` this command in a detached container?

Comment: Can you try `docker exec -id jupyterbox bash -c labserve`? For your second method, you can detach from the running container by doing  `Ctrl+p + Ctrl+q`. Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#extended-description

Comment: That seems to do something; I get a "connection was reset" error (rather than an "unable to connect" error).  I'd like to run the docker exec from a bash script on the host machine, so the `Ctrl+p + Crtl+q` method doesn't quite work.